# How can I read a config file in my bixby capsule code

Tags: bixby

I am trying to read a CSV file and config file into my capsule code. Please let me know what is the best way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Bixby provides a properties [file](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/ref-topics/capsule-properties) per capsule. You can add your entries to this file. That would be the easiest way to get your config file into the capsule.

One of the ways to import a CSV file (and the config file as well) is through a REST enabled service that has access to the CSV file. See [`http.getUrl`](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/JavaScriptAPI/http). Checkout other compatible [protocols](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.js-actions#calling-web-services) that Bixby can use.